# Does the replicating process consume any of the bulk matter it converts?

Tags: star-trek

When they use the replicators on the Enterprise, does the bulk matter being processed give a 1 to 1 return or is some of the material lost?

Comment: I'm guessing this question is restricted to TNG?

Comment: @Izkata I don't know why you'd guess that.  Over half of all TV shows and movies across the franchise take place after the introduction of replicator technology.  ENT, 2k9, and TOS are the outliers.  TNG, DS9, and VOY all had replicators.

Comment: @Iszi TNG/DS9/VOY and the TNG movies are the only ones with replicators - but DS9/VOY don't take place on an "Enterprise".  (And the "technobabble" in VOY indicates they work differently than they did in TNG)

Comment: Real life Replicator http://store.makerbot.com/replicator2x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't been able to find anything more definitive than this:

Source: *[Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual (ISBN 0-671-70427-3)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671704273)*

Much of this answer is paraphrase the contents of several pages into a few paragraphs. *Please forgive the lack of actual quotes.  This answer is long enough as it is.*

---

The Replicators are based on Transporter technology, with only one significant difference:   Transporters use the quantum scanners to scan objects to "read" the patterns as part of the transport sequence.  Replicators, instead, use patterns stored in memory in the computer system.  Otherwise, the systems are identical.  (Pages 90-91)

It's important to note that living beings are scanned in a Transporter at a Quantum level, but materials can be scanned at a lower resolution for energy savings. The reason living beings need to be scanned at the quantum resolution is that failure to do so introduces more "errors" - an imperfect reassembly of matter at the end of the transport cycle.  These small errors would add up over time, causing noticeable physical effects on living tissue.

Armed with this knowledge, logic dictates that there is no loss of matter as part of the process itself.

Given the absolutely miniscule margin for errors in transporters, ***any*** loss of matter would, over repeated transports, cause symptoms.  Scrambled DNA, cellular damage, etc.  It stands to reason that ***with transporters, there can be no loss of matter without serious consequences***.

Taking the next step, since replicators are simply transporters with stored patterns in place of the scanning/imaging array, there is also likely no loss in matter.  The components are all the same *except for the source of the patterns*.

The different source of the patterns may affect how accurately a pattern is recreated.  A quantum scan has more bits than a finitely stored file in a computer, but it is the transmission/matter assembly components that are responsible for grabbing the correct amount of source matter and reassembling it into the final product.

***Since these are the same components in both systems, it stands to reason that food replicators, like transporters, reassemble 100% 0f the matter that they consume, with no loss in the process.***

Comment: The implications of these 'errors' adding up in common food items are horrifying.  *Cracks open a loaf of bread* "...Hah.  Tumors."

Comment: @zibbobz - The book says that "nano-scale  voids" are tolerated by the replicator system, not ruddy great cracks

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_%28Star_Trek%29) on the replicator, it works by reassembeling subatomic particles into whatever is needed. According to the [Laws of Conservation](http://www.cartage.org.lb/en/themes/Sciences/Chemistry/Generalchemistry/Energy/LawofConservation/LawofConservation.htm),

> Law of Conservation of Matter: During an ordinary chemical change, there is no detectable increase or decrease in the quantity of matter.

So in Theory the only thing expended during the replication process is energy. The matter made had to come from somewhere, but there is no way any of the matter would be lost in the process.

Comment: As you say "During an **ordinary chemical** change" -- That hardly describes the crazy stuff the replicator does.

Answer (score 0):

In Section 13.5 page 153, in the food replication section of the ST:TNG Technical Manual, it mentions reprocessing of biological waste back into usable food is 82% efficient.  That suggests a maximum of 18% of the input matter can be lost during replicator processing, otherwise the number would be closer to 100% instead of 82%.

Even taking into account losses to the atmosphere and water from CO2 and H20 metabolic products, a significant percentage seems to be lost based on this 82% figure.

One could easily build into the machinery the ability to reclaim mass from air and water, so I'm inclined to think that 82% food reclamation ability is a measure of the 18% mass lost during replicator processing.

(The real reason for the 82% figure is to give ST a reason to stop for food supplies.  If the figure were 100%, barring energy usage, no starship with food replicators would ever have a story reason to run out of food and find supplies.)

Comment: Except that this figure relates to physical waste processing (e.g of faeces and waste-water back into usable matter that the replicator can use), not de-replication technology. As such, this answer is totally irrelevant to the question

Comment: @Richard Clarify? The same mass is involved whether we're talking waste or any other kind of matter.  The waste matter is reprocessed into a supsension that requires the least amount of quantum manipulation to replicate back into food.  Unless the waste reclamation process loses that 18% (a huge loss given the closed ship ecosystem), that 18% loss represents replicator losses not waste reclamation inefficiencies.  Even passing the sludge unprocessed directly into the replicator system would lose even more mass given that it no longer optimizes replicator power requirements.

Comment: The system you've described isn't part of the replicator system. In itself, that's enough to completely invalidate the answer.

Comment: @Richard We're dealing with a closed ship ecosystem. Reprocessing of waste matter is a physical and chemical process that at most can lose a far less than 1% of the mass (think 10's of EV compared with the 936 MEV per proton so it's less than a millionth loss).  Maybe we'd get methane and other outgassing but it's a CLOSED system.  We're not venting methane to space, and it would be stupid to lose our mass that way.  Even today's reclamation wouldn't do that.  That leaves the 18% loss to the replicator itself.  The section says it.  I'm not big on it but we're stuck with it.

Comment: The quote is that the process of turning "waste water" to usable foodstock is carried out by "osmotic and electrolytic fractioning", e.g. not by the replicator. It seems pretty clear to me that it's a separate system.